# Scalaz - runnable monad

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

Is there in Scalaz any concept of a "runnable" monad? - one from which the result value can be extracted, potentially by hidden side effects?

```
trait RunnableM[M[_]] {
  def runM[T](m: M[T]): T
}
```

I would need this to evaluate a monadic computation and exit from the monad at the end. In Haskell we have different "run" functions for monads which might or might not involve IO, so a typeclass of this sort might not be possible, at least to my thinking. But in Scala it could be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a "correct" solution, but scalaz's `Comonad` has `copoint`, which can be (ab)used to achieve this; `Comonad` instances already exist for a lot of standard scalaz monads, and you can cheat and define one for e.g. `Task` (this may make theorists angry; be sure to limit the scope of any such instance to where you need it and are happy for IO to happen, don't let it infect distant code). It's pimped onto instances:

```
def runM[T](m: M[T])(implicit cm: Comonad[M]) = m.copoint
```

Comment: I just need this for testing purposes. I don't know a lot about `Comonad` - is this its primary purpose? To extract values from monads?

Comment: Its primary purpose is for composing functions of shape `M[A] => B`. There used to (in scalaz 6) be a distinct `Copoint` type just for extracting values like you want to, but it was abandoned; Tony Morris gets very shouty about how it was a bad idea but doesn't explain what the actual problem was, so I don't know why. (If I had to guess, I'd imagine the argument is that `Copoint` is lawless so you can't possibly write anything useful with it, because there's nothing you can know about what it does to generic `M`).